# Angular language service doesnt intellisense _variable

Tags: html, angular, angular5

I am using `Visual Studio Code` for `Angular 5` project I have converted my post JSON data into typeScript file like

```
//interface class of post data
export interface Client {
  ctm_id: number;
  firstname: string;
  middlename: string;
}

//interface class of post data
export interface ClientContact {
  phone: number;
  alternate_phone: number;
}

//interface class of post data
export interface ClientPostData {
  client: Client;
  clientContacts: ClientContact;
  clientMedical_info:Clientmedicalinfo;
}

// and declared in component class like     
export class FormComponent implements OnInit {
  public model: ClientPostData = <ClientPostData>{};
  public ffirst_name:string;
}
```

I have installed Angular language service to get suggestions for variables from the interface.

When I type f it suggests firstname in html.but it doesn't suggest clientMedical_info when I type model.(dot).It suggests model.clients and model.clientContacts

How can I get suggestion of client_contact when I type model.(dot)

Comment: Instead of `public model: ClientPostData = <ClientPostData>{};`, did you try `public model: ClientPostData = new ClientPostData();` ? I assume that `{} as ClientPostData` is different from object `{
  client: undefined,
  clientContacts: undefined,
  clientMedical_info: undefined
}` (this is what you get from the constructor ...

Comment: Sorry that is not my question and I cant assign a constructor because its not a class its a interface.My question is how to get a intellisense in html when i click on modeel.(dot) for variable with (_).for example clientMedical_info varible when i type model.client.(dot)

Comment: I misread your question and you are totally right, an interface does not have a constructor. I read class instead of interface... Anyways, Intellisense does not seems to support underscore in property name in html (I have done a quick test on Stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-myzcfw?file=src/app/app.component.ts). On the other hand, the convention is to name your variable in lower camel case like you did it in `client` and `clientContacs` https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#interfaces

Comment: But I dont want to use camelcase as my api has (_) in variables.Can I somwhow add or do somwhhing to accept the _variable.Becasue It will take underscore if i declare in the component class (FormComponent) as i mentioned above